# Chkdsk /f /r /x stuck

Tags: hard-drive

I know there a few topics out there, but the question I have differs.

It got stuck here: timer never went down past 16% and the ETA got stuck

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
Disk checking has been cancelled.                        : 16%; ETA:  21:43:23 ...

**So now the facts:**

a) I'm aware this hard drive has bad sectors - was running this to see what the outcome would be.

b) I'm **not** trying to get it unstuck to complete nor asking on what things / solutions i can do to get it to complete.

So the question is: Given the above - is it indicative of a failure and the drive being useless and basically what causes this to get stuck?

as i was attempting to format and either *sell or heavily discounted sell* so somewhat seeing if ***either is viable or should it go to trash***.

Comment: "was running this to see what the outcome would be" - now you know. Look at SMART first, a tool like Victoria for Windows can tell + it allows you to remap bad sectors. It's to some degree opinion driven, some are more forgiving with regards to a few bad sectors others have zero tolerance.

Comment: in the smart data, look for reallocated sector count, pending sector count, uncorrectable sector count, and raw read errors. if any of those are beyond their threshold, its time to replace the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drive like this should go in the trash.

1. If you sold it, you would have to disclose the bad sector situation
2. Hard drives are generally, one the way out especially at sizes <=2tb.
3. What is the size of the drive?  2TB SSD are now $110, capacities equal to or less than this definitely favor SSD and not hdd.
4. Is the $20 you might get for it worth the effort?
5. Given how cheap most hard drives are currently, people would buy at better drive from someone else.

If you sell it on ebay, or etc even properly labelled as bad you might have fight a charge back claim from your customer or their credit card company.

Comment: To your other question, its 6TB :)